# Erro: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, jdbc

Estou tentando remover um dado do banco, mas acontece o seguinte erro:

> Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Podem me ajudar?

```java
public void remove(Bean e) {
     try {

         PreparedStatement stmt = ConexaoMysql.getConexao()
                 .prepareStatement("DELETE FROM coluna WHERE id = 5");


         stmt.setInt(1,e.getId());
         stmt.execute();
         stmt.close();
         System.out.println("Removido!");
     } catch (SQLException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
 }
```

```java
public class TesteRemover {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bean p = new Bean ();  

         Dao dao = new Dao (); 

          p.setIdexemplo(5); 

          dao.remove(p);  


    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve usar ***"?"*** para indicar os parâmetros que serão atribuídos no [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), no caso você explicitou o valor literal ***"5"*** e está tentando efetuar o bind, por isso ocorre o *"Parameter index out of range"*.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = ConexaoMysql.getConexao()
                 .prepareStatement("DELETE FROM coluna WHERE id = ?");
```

Comment: Mas mesmo assim meu dado não é removido

Comment: @Joãosouza tente forçar o valor do id (inteiro) a ser removido, do preparedStatement por exemplo, stmt.setInt(1,5);   Me parece que seu e.getId();  não se refere ao mesmo atributo do p.setIdexemplo(5);  mas pra ter certeza disso seria necessário você adicionar o fonte da classe Bean;

Comment: Percebi que voce alterou o SQL inicial da pergunta vou alterar a responda para manter a coerência.

Comment: "Forçando" o dado é removido mas eu queria remover pelo meu main.

Comment: tente trocar o stmt.setInt(1,e.getId()); por algo do tipo stmt.setInt(1,e.getIdexemplo());

Comment: Nada............

Comment: adicione o fonte de sua Classe Bean questão

Comment: private int id;
 private String nome;
 private float numero;
 private Calendar data;

Comment: Essa é a minha bean

Comment: Joao voce precisa adicionar o fonte na questão de forma completa para que eu possa analisar e te ajudar, o que provavelmente está acontecendo é que você não está setando o mesmo atributo que você esta dando get.

Comment: o problema estava no bean, já resolvi obrigado :)